# SqlCommandBuilder generating incorrect update statement

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ado.net

I am trying to use a `SqlDataAdapter` to update a table in a database.

I retrieve the schema from the table, and it populates the `DataTable` correctly with the columns and the primary key. There is only one constraint in the `DataTable`, and it is the correct three PK columns.

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
DataTable dt = ds.Tables.Add(tableName);
adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from " + tableName, connection);
adapter.FillSchema(dt, SchemaType.Source);

// Add datarows
```

I create a `SqlCommandBuilder` for the adapter, ...

```
SqlCommandBuilder cmdBld = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter);
```

... but the update command it generates includes a lot of field combinations in the `WHERE` clause that aren't the primary key. From what I read, the builder should generate the update statement based on the PK constraint of the `DataTable`:

```
UPDATE [MyTable] 
SET [CCode] = @p1, 
    [RefNumber] = @p2, 
    [BrandId] = @p3, 
    [BasePrice1] = @p4, 
    [BasePrice2] = @p5,
    ....
WHERE 
    (([CCode] = @p14) -- PK
    AND ([RefNumber] = @p15) -- PK
    AND ([BrandId] = @p16) -- PK
    AND ([BasePrice1] = @p17)
    AND ([BasePrice2] = @p18)
    AND ((@p19 = 1 AND [AddedBy] IS NULL) OR ([AddedBy] = @p20))
    AND ((@p21 = 1 AND [SFlag] IS NULL) OR ([SFlag] = @p22))
    AND ((@p23 = 1 AND [CartonCode] IS NULL) OR ([CartonCode] = @p24))
    AND ((@p25 = 1 AND [AvailableOrder] IS NULL) OR ([AvailableOrder] = @p26))
    AND ((@p27 = 1 AND [AvailableRegistration] IS NULL) OR ([AvailableRegistration] = @p28))
    AND ((@p29 = 1 AND [IsFOC] IS NULL) OR ([IsFOC] = @p30))
    AND ((@p31 = 1 AND [ItemBrand] IS NULL) OR ([ItemBrand] = @p32))
    AND ((@p33 = 1 AND [QuantityMultiply] IS NULL) OR ([QuantityMultiply] = @p34)))
```

Can anyone help me understand why I'm not getting the expected, PK-based update command?

Thanks.

Comment: The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/generating-commands-with-commandbuilders?view=netframework-4.8) states that it uses the "optimistic concurrency" approach - so the where clause attempts to ignore updates that logically change nothing.

Comment: Yep. Post that as an answer, and I'll accept. Thanks! And thanks for editing @marc_s

Answer (score 0):

This answer is a bit late, but have a look at the SqlCommandBuilder.ConflictOption property. The default is: CompareAllSearchableValues, which is the behaviour you are seeing. If you only want to check the primary key, try using OverwriteChanges.

e.g.

```
SqlCommandBuilder cmdBld = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter);
cmdBld.ConflictOption = ConflictOption.OverwriteChanges;
```

Reference on ConflictOption Enum: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.conflictoption?view=netframework-4.8